# Get the substring after particular separator

Tags: java

I an trying to get the number after `:` of the element string `Min:30` to store it in int variable but I am getting a wrong result `5` as Output. How can I get the substring (the number) after `:` in the element string?

```
if( element.startsWith("Min:") ) {
    char[] Str = new char[2];
    element.getChars(4, 6, Str, 0);

    String string = str.toString();
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int colonIndex = element.indexOf(":");
int value = Integer.parseInt(element.substring(colonIndex + 1, element.length()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use String.split();

```
element.split(":");
```

which returns an array splitted by the specified delimiter

```
String [] result  = "Min:30".split(":"); //result[1]=30
int value = Integer.parseInt(result[1]);
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative to the answer I gave.